# How to find distance between two geo points in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

I want to find distance between two geo points and show the distance in kilometers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Coordinates a = new Coordinates(Lat_A,Lon_A,Float.NaN);
Coordinates b = new Coordinates(Lat_B,Lon_B,Float.NaN);
float distance = a.distance(b)/1000;
```

Answer (score 2):

check out the formula's on this page [Calculate distance and bearing between geolocations](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)